# Safari change dom on before unload page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I wan't to show a loader when I switch page on my website. So I define a loader in my HTML:

```
<div class="ajax-loader"><i class="icon-spin5"></i></div>
```

And in my CSS:

```
.ajax-loader {
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50vh;
    left: 50vw;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: white;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all ease-in-out .25s;

    i {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 80px;
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        animation: spin 3s linear infinite;

        @media @step1, @step2 {
            font-size: 2em;
        }
    }

    &.active {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

And in my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // loader on page change
    window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
        // show ajax loader
        $('.ajax-loader').addClass('active');
    };
});
```

All is fine, in IE, Firefox, Chrome... but not in Safari (Mac + iOS).

Any idea ?
Thanks !

Comment: The only thing the `beforeunload` listener is supposed to do is return a string, which some browsers will display in the dialog that asks the user to confirm whether they want to leave the page.

Comment: What's the point of changing the DOM? As soon as the handler returns, the page is unloaded, so you don't see the current DOM any more.

Comment: My loader is showed (opacity 0 to 1) with my JS (addClass active). It works perfectly on all browsers but not in Safari...

Comment: Did you resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps missing the -webkit-transition and -webkit-transform in your css

Answer (score 0):

Probably `document.pagehide` will work for Safari.

```
document.pagehide = function(e) {
    $('.ajax-loader').addClass('active');
};
```