# Display loading indicator when navigating away from page on Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, webkit

I would like to display a nice page transition when navigating between pages on a site.

I've tried using these events: `beforeunload unload pagehide` and also `visibilitychange`.

There [was a webkit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=151234) described as

> visibilitychange:hidden doesn't fire during page navigations

And a workaround is listed:

> using the pagehide event is the workaround

I am adding a class to the html element on these events.  On Chrome and Firefox this activates my loading indicator class and the animation is displayed until the page is replaced.  I get a nice loading transition between page navigation. So, in Chrome and Firefox, everything works great.

Unfortunately, I am not having any luck with Safari on iOS (iPhone or iPad) and also failing on macOS Big Sur Safari.  I found a related question here: [Safari change dom on before unload page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308042/safari-change-dom-on-before-unload-page) however, it only discusses the `beforeunload` event.  I am hoping that by being less specific here that a viable alternative pops up.

I have tested the css works on Safari by manually applying it and also verified my listeners are called on Safari via the javascript console.  However the css change doesn't seem to be rendered.  There is no transition shown on the page being unloaded before getting the new page response from the server.  I've also verified it isn't related to the CSS in use by setting a simple background color without any transition or similar effects.

So far, the only way that I have been able to get Safari to render the dom change is by returning a truthy string on unload - but this prompts the user if they want to leave or not which is not my intention.

I want to avoid browser detection - however the last viable alternative I can come up with is scanning the dom for anchors, buttons, forms, etc when Safari is detected to enable the loading indicator before navigating.

Are there any other options to consider?

Comment: Did you find other options? And if not, what did you end up doing (please add some could.) Thank you.l

Comment: Any update on this?